# Let $(a_n)$ be a non-decreasing and unbounded sequence. Show that $\lim a_n = \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(a_n)$ be a non-decreasing and unbounded sequence.
>
> Show that $\lim a_n = \infty$

I realize you can always pick a $n + 1$ such that $n + 1 > n$, because the sequence is non-decreasing and unbounded.

But I don't think this is the way to go.

Comment: What does crescent mean? Is that just nondecreasing? (i.e., $a_{n} \leq a_{n+1}$)

Comment: I don't know exactly what term to use in English, but yeah, this is it

Comment: Nondecreasing is the usual term.

Comment: Personally, I think "nondecreasing" is a terrible term, since it's really easy to confuse with "not decreasing", which is something else entirely. "Increasing" is a better term (with "strictly increasing" if it's increasing with none of the terms equal, being consistent with the difference between "greater than" and "strictly greater than").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_n$ is unbounded means for any $M>0$ there exists $N$ such that $a_N\ge M$

Now since $a_n$ is non-drcreasing for every $n>N$ we have $$a_n\ge a_N\ge M$$

this prove the statement that is $a_n\to\infty$